# Can my identity be revealed to the receiver when using skype to land line phone service?

Tags: skype

I have been using skype for online chats, and recently called my company on their landline number through skype a few times regarding an anonymous complaint to avoid retaliation. I have not used caller identification but is there any possibility that the company can track my identity?

Comment: This is more of a question for Skype support

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**The answer is maybe, but it isn't likely.**

(Assuming that your company isn't the cyber mob and can't hack and slash their way through the internet)

One example of a case where you could be found out; say your company decided that the complaint was somehow incriminating, if it was they could press charges and attempt to get a subpoena for your information. Assuming Skype keeps accessible logs on activities such as calls through their phone systems, the police could legally get Skype search for who was using the phone number that called the company at the time and fork over everything they've got on that person. If you didn't use a proxy or a VPN or some other means of routing your traffic around, they could give your Internet Service Provider a call and then get a name and address for you.

Comment: Claims such as "Skype has been infested with government backdoors" really needs to be backed up with more vague allegations (I'm not disputing the fact that Skype can be eavesdropped by several governments, mind you). Furthermore, I'm not sure that this is really relevant in the case mentioned by the OP.

Comment: You're right haha, I apologize. I corrected my answer.